# How to setup error page handling for subdomains?

Tags: asp.net

On my hosting server I want to achieve the following arhitecture of main site and subdomains:

```
www.site.com
subdomain1.site.com
subdomain2.site.com
```

All three domain have some common resources: scripts, css files, images and custom error files to present errors like 404, 503 in a creative intriguing and most entertaining way.

I have organized folders on my hosting server into this structure

```
www-main
www-subdomain1
www-subdomain2
shared-css
shared-errors
```

I have setup each subdomain as an asp.net applicatin which resides in its physical folder.
To access common shared resources I have created virtual folders for each subdomain that point to the sam physical folders.

```
virtual folder shared-css in subdomain1 points to   shared-css physical folder
virtual folder shared-css in subdomain2 points to   shared-css physical folder
```

This works ok. But not  for folder containing error files. I have configured my web.config and files according to http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-mvc-custom-error-pages

The problem is that it does not work for subdomains. If I configure virtual folder as asp.net application it complains it cannot load assemblies for the application for which this folder was created. On the other hand if I configure it as ASp folder it simply does not work.

This same concept works if site is not divided into subdomains but into subfolders instead of subdomains.
Does anybody has a working solution for this problem?
Not suggestions, I have tried many things, anything I could think of.

Comment: Are your error pages dynamic or static? Are you using MVC or plain aspx? Are you using customErrors or httpErrors in web.config? And do you want to preserve HTTP error codes or return 200 OK?

Comment: The are both static and dynamic. I use plain aspx. I use customErrors and httpErros as per  http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-mvc-custom-error-pages. I want to preserve error codes.

Comment: Do you have web.config for each web site?i.e. one main, and two subdomains?

Comment: @CreativeManix Yes, of course. In each subdoain is different app. It is just I want to use consitent eror pages .